# Adobe Lightroom Catalog API returns code+JSON

Tags: adobe, adobecreativesdk, lightroom, creative-cloud

When using the [Adobe Lightroom Catalog API](https://www.adobe.io/apis/creativecloud/lightroom/apidocs.html#/catalogs/getCatalog) to access the catalogs in a Lightroom account, the resulting data is a combination of code and JSON starting with:

```
while (1) {}\n{\"base\":\"https://lr.adobe.io/v2/\",\"id\":\"7afe....
```

This is different from the documentation which only specifies the JSON.

1. Can I safely trim the "while (1) {} at the beginning
2. Should I modify my request
3. Should I do other changes to GET response string as well?

Answer (score 0):

Yes,  you can safely trim off the `while (1) {}` part.

It is simply a security measure to prevent automatic execution of malicious code hidden inside the json structure.

Unfortunately, this can make your code more complicated. Instead of a simple

```
const data = await fetch('https://lr.adobe.io/v2')
    .then((response) => response.json());
```

you must do something like this:

```
const data = await fetch('https://lr.adobe.io/v2')
    .then((response) => response.text())
    .then((text) => text.replace('while (1) {}', ''))
    .then((json) => JSON.parse(json.trim()));
```